# PHP not receiving JSON from Ajax post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am trying to send some **JSON to a PHP** processing code **via Ajax**. Here is my **JavaScript**:

```
var j = {"a":"b"};
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
};
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        console.log(xmlhttp.responseText)
    };
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", "server.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
xmlhttp.send({
    "json": j
});
```

And the **PHP**:

```
$json = $_POST["json"];
echo $json;
```

But this echoes `null`. **What have I done wrong? This seems like it should work. Thanks!**

*Please no jQuery. And if you vote down, please tell me why so I can improve.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `j` variable is a object. You need to encode this into a json string before you post it.

*Okay I have re-written my answer from scratch.*

Update your **server.php** like this:

```
<?php

// Request Handler
if (count($_POST))
{
    $json = isset($_POST['json']) ? $_POST['json'] : '';
    if (!empty($json))
    {
        $jsonObj = json_decode($json);
        print_r($jsonObj);
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No json string detected";
    }
    exit();
}

?>
```

Change your ajax request like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var j = {"a":"b"};

var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var parameters = "json="+ encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(j));
xmlHttp.open("POST", "server.php", true);

xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
        console.log(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
}

xmlHttp.send(parameters)

</script>
```

Here's a demo of it working:

[image]

---

So, in the PHP script, I am printing the `$jsonObj` and it's contents. If you want to use it in your script; you'd do this:

e.g.

```
<?php

if ($jsonObj->a == 'b') {
    // do something ?
}

?>
```

If you want an associative array to work with (instead of an object), you can do this:

Change: `$jsonObj = json_decode($json);` To: `$jsonObj = json_decode($json, true);`

Now you can do this:

```
<?php

if ($jsonObj['a'] == 'b') {
    // do something ?
}

?>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Are you getting an error? I've updated my answer to include the update to the PHP script also.

Comment: I've updated my answer again. You might need to URL Encode the json string after you stringify the object.

Comment: Ok, I am getting `No json string detected`. I did add `encodeURIComponent` too.

Comment: try using `$json = isset($_REQUEST['json']) ? $_REQUEST['json'] : '';` I suspect the data isn't in the `$_POST` variable.

Comment: This won't work, you're telling the endpoint that you're sending json, but then sending a querystring.

Comment: Okay, there's quite a bit to re-write; so I have re-written my answer from scratch. See updated answer. It works now.

Comment: @LatheesanKanes I have yet to test out your new answer, it looks like it will work. Why did you set the `Connection` and `Content-length` headers though?

Comment: for the benefit of the web-server to process your request correctly.

Comment: I just checked it. It works! Thanks! +1 and accept. I did have to add `stripslashes()` to when the `$json` variable is declared.

Answer (score 0):

Javascipt :

```
encode en JSON  with JSON.stringify(j);
```

if j contain & in string and not a separator de data :

```
j.split("&").join("%26");
```

in php

```
$json = $_REQUEST['json'];
$json = str_replace("%26","&",$jsonData);
$json = html_entity_decode($json,ENT_NOQUOTES,'UTF-8');
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

the value of json as array of data.

Answer (score 0):

To submit JSON properly, it'd be:

```
xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({"json": j});
```

Then for the PHP:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

The problem is that when sending JSON (if it's a proper JSON request), PHP won't automatically parse it.